# Deployment of dianoga or dianoga.imagemagic to Test environment

Tags: dianoga

How to deploy dianoga or dianoga.imagemagic with sitecore to test environment? 
I am using buildmaster to deploy the web application to test environment. By the normal build it's not deployed to test environment. I have tried to just send the build with the nuget package reference in .csproj file.

Is there any other way to deploy Dianoga or Dianoga.Imagemagic to next level of environments like Test, UAT, Prod etc?

How to check dianoga.imagemagic is working on test environment?

Where can I find logs specifically for dianoga.imagemagic in my application? Any other way to validate the working of Dianoga.imagemagic.

Any help or pointer will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to deploy Dianoga is via nuget with your solution.  As long as you add the Nuget package and your build pipeline is doing a Nuget restore as part of the deployment, then the resulting deployment should have everything Dianoga needs to operate.  You can confirm by checking that the built solution contains the appropriate assembly (bin\Dianoga.dll), configs (in App_Config\Include\Dianoga*) and tools (App_Data\Dianoga Tools*)

Although the recommended install method is via Nuget, Dianoga can be installed manually, as per installation notes at https://github.com/kamsar/Dianoga

> To perform a manual installation:
>
> - Copy the Dianoga Tools folder to the App_Data folder of your website
> - Copy Default Config Files/*.config to App_Config\Include\Dianoga
> - Reference Dianoga.dll or the source project in your web project

To confirm Dianoga is working, check your Sitecore application logs (in AppData\Logs for a default on prem Sitecore 9+ install).  If all is ok, there will be INFO level entries beginning with *Dianoga* giving the stats on the files optimised.

Don't forget to clear your App_Data/MediaCache folder on the target server! Otherwise unoptimized images in the cache will continue to be served.

Installing Dianoga.ImageMagick is a similar process, just a different Nuget package (that has a dependency on Dianoga).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i have done deployment in distributed mode. Config files and reference to the dll included in normal build and Dianoga Tools folder copied manually. So far its working fine.